# Search result difference for the same Tokenizers from solr 5 to 8

Tags: java, indexing, solr, lucene, solrcloud

I have indexed records which contains a filed called birth-date , its not a stored field and also not a date field , it is a text field (solr.TextField) , with a "standard Tokenizers" . In solr 5 when I did a search query

`q=*:*&fq=birth_date:1989/01/01`

I got filtered 33 odd records but when I am doing the same in solr 8 (with the same property ) ,I get more than 6000 results .

Below is the schema of the field

```
<fieldtype name='birth_date' class='solr.TextField' sortMissingLast='true' omitNorms='true'\>
   <analyzer\>
      <tokenizer class='solr.StandardTokenizerFactory'/\>
   </analyzer\>
</fieldtype\>

<field name='birth_date' type='birth_date' indexed='true' stored='false' multiValued='false' required='false'/\>
```

From solr 5 to 8 I don't see any change in solr.StandardTokenizerFactory but I did notice default "similarity" has changed , wanted to know why the search not giving same output

tied to hit `q=*:*&fq=birth_date:1989/01/01`  , we should get same number of response in solr 5 and solr 8

Comment: If similarity model is changes then it may impact your search output

Comment: I can see in the solr document similarity model has changed from default to BM25Similarity

Comment: yes...I have seen this in Elasticsearch as well where they have changes the default similarity model to BM25 and it has a different scoring formula than earlier TF/IDF ....hence you are facing this different search outputs

Comment: but from document they have removed the default similarity class itself since 6 ? solr 5 response is the correct and desired response and I wanted to implement that in solr 8 too

Comment: check if you write your own custom similarity class and use in the schema.xml of solr

Comment: A change of similarity model would only affect the scores calculated, not the number of entries returned. There might be a difference in how your date string gets tokenized, but generally: if you want to index a birth date, either use a date field with iso format, or if you want to keep this format, use a keyword tokenized field instead to avoid having it be split into `1989`, `01` and `01`.

Comment: In solr 5 I was using solr.StandardTokenizerFactory and when I search with qf I was able to get the correct set of response, but with the same tokeniser I have to add "" to get the same result. 

in solr 5 : fq=birth_date:1989/01/01 
in solr 8 : fq=birth_date:"1989/01/01"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging the input query saw that in solr5 the query searched was performing filter

```
"parsed_filter_queries": [
  "PhraseQuery(birth_date:\"1989 01 01\")"
]
```

But in solr 8 it was searching as

"parsed_filter_queries":["birth_date:1989 birth_date:01 birth_date:01"]

only after adding double quotes in the fq it changed to phrase query

**Another workaround was to use**

```
<fieldtype name="birth_date" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
   <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([^0-9])" replacement="" replace="all" />
   </analyzer>
   <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([^0-9])" replacement="" replace="all" />
   </analyzer>
</fieldtype>
```

where the query eliminates all special character except numbers